# jMeter How to get Multipart body in BeanShell PreProcessor

Tags: jmeter

In `jMeter` How to get multi part body in `BeanShell PreProcessor`
I need to get the image data and post parameters

by using `sampler.getArguments();` I am able to get the post parameters but not the image file

Please help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [getHTTPFiles](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/http/sampler/HTTPSamplerBase.html#getHTTPFiles()) method of Sampler API.

`sampler.getHTTPFiles()` will return the file path [HTTPFileArg](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/http/util/HTTPFileArg.html) in an array through which you can update new file at run time.

**Update:**

```
String path = sampler.getHTTPFiles()[0].getPath();
byte[] array = Files.readAllBytes(new File(path).toPath());
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like:

```
File image = new File(sampler.getHTTPFiles()[0].getPath());
//do what you need with the image file
```

If you need extended image information take a look at [ImageIO](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html). For more Beanshell tips and tricks check out [How to Use BeanShell: JMeter's Favorite Built-in Component](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell)